# SQL Server select difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]
Dears,

I want to get time difference between two dates in DATESTAMP column between two types only "Open" & "Status Change".
I wrote this query, but i got null and error message

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = (Select Datestamp from ACTIVITYM1 where TYPE='Open')
set @EndDate = (Select Datestamp from ACTIVITYM1 where TYPE='Status Change')
select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
from ACTIVITYM1
```

below is the error i got
[image]

Comment: The two select you assign with the set return more than one rows. That's why you get the error.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the error message: "Subquery returned more than 1 value...".
You need to select only one row, e.g.:

`set @StartDate = (Select Datestamp from ACTIVITYM1 where TYPE='Open' AND THENUMBER = '001A1419')`

or set an limit to your query...

Comment: Thanx Alexander, yes it's working for a specific NUMBER, but if i want to select more than one NUMBER, this is the challenge.